# Formidable - Error on PUT

Tags: javascript, node.js, formidable

I'm trying to upload files to my NodeJS server.
I'm currently getting the error:

`Error: bad content-type header, unknown content-type: image/jpeg`

"image/jpeg" is a valid mime-type, why am I getting this error?

---

CODE:

```
var formidable = require("formidable");

var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.maxFieldsSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;

form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    //if (err) {
    //    res.writeHead(412);
    //    res.end();
    //}
    console.log(err, fields, files);
});
```

Client:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("PUT", "", false);
xmlHttp.send(fileInput.files[0]);
```

Comment: Can you put your client-side code ? I don't think it comes from your Node server.

Comment: I added (an abstracted version of) the client side code

Comment: It was working fine before I started using the formidable library. I don't even know what you mean by that.

Comment: Oh my bad, yes it supports it now. Sorry.

Comment: Does it matter if `Content-Type` is uppercase vs lowercase?  (I'm gonna guess probably not....)

Comment: I do not think so, why do you ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) is "A node.js module for parsing form data, especially file uploads."

It is designed to handle POST requests formatted as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

It isn't designed to process plain PUTs of single files.

If you want to PUT an uploaded JPEG, then just read the raw HTTP request body. You don't need to parse it!

Comment: I was reading the RAW body before, with single uploads; however, I wish to implement more complicated uploads with multiple files etc. And I want some consistency with how uploads are handled in my application. Reverting back isn't a solution, does one need to use the FormData API?

Comment: FormData is the most sensible way to do that.